# Do you know how to properly achieve this layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a layout like:

[image]

But is not working, the layout appears like https://jsfiddle.net/0knckvfh/1/. Do you know where is the issue?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Title</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> emailtest...</p>
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">User 1</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Surname:</strong> Y</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong>emailtest...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have no column (`.col`) in your `.row`. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0knckvfh/3/). Also please read the Bootstrap docs on how [the grid system works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

Comment: follow bootstrap rules ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout is displaying incorrectly because you have forgotten to wrap your content within one of Bootstrap's `.col-*-*` classes.  Without that wrapper everything defaults to `flex-wrap: wrap` as defined by the `row`.

If you're just learning Bootstrap this would be an opportune moment to read the documentation on its Grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Once you apply the `col` wrapper correctly your code structures *mostly* how you want it.  Applying a few more of Bootstrap's utility classes results in your code looking something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Title</h6>
      <p><strong class="mr-1">Name:</strong>John</p>
      <p><strong class="mr-1">Email:</strong>emailtest...</p>

      <h6 class="font-weight-bold border-top pt-3">User 1</h6>
      <p><strong class="mr-1">Name:</strong>John</p>
      <p><strong class="mr-1">Surname:</strong>Y</p>
      <p><strong class="mr-1">Email:</strong>emailtest...</p>
  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to acknowledge that @zgood correctly noted this issue in the comments to your initial post.  Why so many people followed that comment with answers involving the nonexistent 'column' class is beyond me.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="column">

    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Title</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> emailtest...</p>
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">User 1</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Surname:</strong> Y</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong>emailtest...</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Will give you what you want, minus the black bar separating the two as shown in your example, but as you didnt include this in your code and you are just after formatting im guessing you know this.

Comment: My answer here add a column div to your layout which is what you were missing. the same result can be achieved by removing the div with class "row". However i do not know if / why you needed this div, and did not want to remove in case you needed it

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Title</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> emailtest...</p>
    <hr>
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">User 1</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Surname:</strong> Y</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong>emailtest...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="column">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Title</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> emailtest...</p>
   </div>
<br/>

   <div class="column">
    <h6 class="font-weight-bold">User 1</h6>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong>  John</p>
    <p><strong>Surname:</strong> Y</p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong>emailtest...</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope helps :)